# enscript error: must print at least one line per page: --no-header

Tags: enscript

I'm getting the following error using RedHat 8 after an upgrade from RedHat 7:

```
error: must print at least one line per page: --no-header
```

Why won't it print a blank page?

Answer (score 0):

--lines-per-page option was messed up. Sorry.